# No such file or directory when trying to create .ssh keys

Tags: jenkins, ssh, gitlab, debian

When I attempt to create ssh keys on my Debian instance :

```
ssh-keygen -f /home/serverkeys/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I am getting the error : *Saving key "/home/serverkeys/.ssh/id_rsa" failed: No such file or directory*

I am using root user and when I check permissions on the directory :

```
 ls -ld
```

I get

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 17 08:32 .
```

I have a number of questions :

1)What am I missing and why is the system not able to automatically create the .ssh directory specified ?

2)Do I need to create another user and switch from using root. I am not sure if the new user will inherit permissions on all packages I have so far since I have installed them with root user profile?

3. I intend to use the ssh keys for integration between Jenkins and Gitlab as outlined here [Jenkins_Gitlab](https://faun.pub/quick-and-easy-ci-cd-with-gitlab-and-jenkins-ba7821032e9c) .In the example however the Jenkins instance and Gitlab instance are installed on ***different servers*** and ***yet for my setup they are installed on the same Debian instance*** and ***also*** ***my Gitlab repo is public***.

I am unsure as to whether I still need the ssh key because Jenkins and Gitlab are running on same Debian instance eg would Jenkins still need ssh keys in order to checkout the code from Gitlab.

Comment: doe the directory /home/serverkeys/,ssh exist? if not maybe try to create it with `mkdir -p /home/serverkeys/.ssh` before executing the command

Answer (score 0):

1. When you want to save your ssh key in a specified folder write the folder name without quotation that works for me.

   Enter file in which to save the key (/home/rakiiibul/.ssh/id_rsa): /home/rakiiibul/Desktop/sshkey
2. Since you are already using a root user you don't need to create another user.[here is screenshot of that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWTl9.png)